# Angularjs Controller return data undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write down a Controller that pass a var to a Factory in Angularjs.. The following code return (in console) the values, but I'm not been able to load that into my html page.

Just to record, yes, I'm starting in angularjs.

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


myApp.factory('eventData', function ($http, $q) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    return {
        getEvent: function (id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'page' + id
            }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('AngularJSCtrl',
    function FeederController($scope, eventData) {
        $scope.data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            eventData.getEvent(i).then(
                function (data) {
                    $scope.data = data;
                    console.log($scope.data);
                },
                function (statusCode) {
                    console.log(statusCode)
                });
        }
    }
);
```

**page.html**

```
<div ng-controller="AngularJSCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="patient in patients">
            <businesscard>{{patient.name}}</businesscard>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: first, `$http` is already a promise, you don't need to wrap it inside a `deferred`. secondly, your code loops through 10 events, queues each one of them up, and when the promise is resolved, each promise is replacing the `$scope.data` array with the single object of that promise.  therefore, `data` is no longer an array and `ng-repeat` has nothing to iterate over.  also, you should try to keep your examples consistent, and not use `data` in your JS and `patients` in your HTML.

Comment: if queuing up 10 promises and then populating the array promise by promise is ***really*** the logic you want to use, you probably should try `$scope.data.push(data)` instead, though I would say that iterating over 10 promises instead of fetching the data as a single unit from the server is fairly inefficient.  also, you are mixing styles again, with the use of `.then` in one snippet and the use of the deprecated `.success` in the other.

Comment: Ok. I'll try clean up the code and make the adjustments you suggested. Thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I've searched for a while until get this right.

Thanks for @Claies and [Brad Barrow](http://www.sitepoint.com/tidy-angular-controllers-factories-services/) for the tips :)

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('patientsData', function ($http) {

    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    return {
        getPatients: function () {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost/ucamradio/php/tst.php?campusId=1',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
    }

});
myApp.controller('AngularJSCtrl', function($scope, patientsData){

    $scope.patients = [];

    var handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
        //$scope.patients = data;
        $scope.patients.push(data);
        console.log($scope.patients);
    };

    patientsData.getPatients().success(handleSuccess);

});
```

**page.html**

```
<div ng-controller="AngularJSCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="patient in patients">
            <businesscard>{{patient.name}}</businesscard>
        </div>
        <!--   
        <div ng-repeat="patient in patients ">
            <businesscard>{{patient.id}}</businesscard>
        </div> -->
    </div>
```